# How can remove"?___from_store=example" from my URL?

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento2.2.4, stores

I want to remove this string "?___from_store=example" from my URL and i dont know how. I have two stories with different language and when I press a diferent Store my url converts to https://website.com/example1/?___from_store=example2

So "/example1/" its the store where i am actually and "=example2" it was the store where i was before.

How can remove this part from URL? https://website.com/example1/**?___from_store=example2**

My URL Options are:

- Add Store Code to URLs -> Yes
- Auto-redirect to Base URL -> Yes(302)

Search Engine Optimization:

- Use Web Server Rewrites -> Yes

If i set Add store Code to URLs as No When you change the store the URL is different -> https://example.com/?___store=example2&___from_store=example1

The string from URL https://website.com/**example1**/?___from_store=example2
dissapear..

Answer (score 0):

Go to system->Configuration.

Then go to web tab. You can see there is an option 'add store code to url set that option to no.. It will remove the default word from your url

also,  check following solution.  It;s same 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267597/force-removal-of-store-code-store-default-from-url-s-in-magento

Comment: I dont have the **path `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Widget/Link.php`**

Comment: You don't have but you need to overwrite the file in local from core folder.

Comment: But I must copy a file that i dont have. When you say **"file in local"** you are refering to **app/code/Magento_Theme/Theme/..**

Comment: @jack: this is about magento2, your solution is limited to magento1